# JavaScript how replace function gets the value from spread syntax?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, replace

I have the following React code,

```
const useDynamicReplaceVariable = ({ label, formikValues, fieldsTypes }) => {
  const { locale } = useTranslationState();

  const formattedLabel = useMemo(() => {
    const variablesRegex = /\?([\w-]+)\?/g;
    let labelResult = label;
    
    if (variablesRegex.test(label)) {
      labelResult = ' ';
      if (Object.keys(formikValues).length > 0) {
        labelResult = label.replace(variablesRegex, (_, ...[variable]) => {
          const type = fieldsTypes[variable];
          // Set undefined or null to empty
          let variableValue = (formikValues[variable] === undefined || formikValues[variable] == null) ? '' : formikValues[variable];
          if (variableValue && [DesignerDdTypes.DatePicker, DesignerDdTypes.DatetimePicker].includes(type)) {
            variableValue = dateToString(variableValue, locale, type === DesignerDdTypes.DatetimePicker);
          }
          return variableValue;
        });
      }
    }
    return labelResult;
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps  
  }, [label, JSON.stringify(formikValues)]);

  return { formattedLabel };
};
```

I can't understand the line `labelResult = label.replace(variablesRegex, (_, ...[variable])`, when no `variable` is defined, how come spread syntax is applied over it?

Comment: it's destructuring the rest parameters to access the first element (of course in this case it is the same as not using rest parameters at all... so it could just be `(_, variable)`)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`...[variable]` is a shorthand for

```
function someFunction(...args) {
  const [variable] = args
}
```

```js
someFunction(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

function someFunction(arg1, ...args) {
  console.log('arg1', arg1)
  console.log('args', args)
  const [variable] = args
  console.log('variable', variable)
}
```

```js
someFunction(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

function someFunction(arg1, ...[variable]) {
  console.log('arg1', arg1)
  console.log('variable', variable)
}
```